# Framework7/Framework7-react dynamic routing cache failure

Tags: reactjs, frameworks

**This is my route React18+framework7 **

{
path: '/PageContainer/:id',
component: PageContainer,
title: 'detail',
},

**My page is dynamic routing. If I jump from dynamic route A to dynamic route B and then to dynamic route C, the page will only cache dynamic route A. I'm not sure why **
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewpQv.png)

```
function PageContainer(props) {
  const { f7router } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('-----test----');
  }, []);
  const zhibiao3 = () => {
    f7router.navigate(`/PageContainer/orderRealtime?${Math.random() * 10000}`);
  };
  const zhibiao4 = () => {
    f7router.navigate(`/PageContainer/orderHistory?${Math.random() * 10000}`);
  };
  return (
    <AppPage>
      <div className={styles.visibleHidden && headerHeight === 0} />
      <div
        className="centerBox"
        style={{
          height: `calc(100vh - ${headerHeight}px)`,
          overflow: 'scroll',
        }}
      >
        <div onClick={zhibiao3}>进入实时</div>
        <div onClick={zhibiao4}>进入单量</div>
      </div>
    </AppPage>
  );
}
```

**This is entry  **

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
import React from 'react';
import { App, View } from 'framework7-react';
import routes from '@/routes';
import '@/App.css';

const f7params = {
  id: 'io.framework7.testapp', // App bundle ID
  name: 'Framework7', // App name
  theme: 'ios', // Automatic theme detection

  pushState: true,
  view: {
    pushState: true,
  },
  routes, // App routes
};

const getViewProps = () => {
  const p = {
    main: true,
    url: '/',
  };
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    p.browserHistory = true;
  }
  return p;
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <App {...f7params} store={store} material>
      <View {...getViewProps()} />
    </App>
  );
};
```

**I expect dynamic routing from A to B to C, with all A and B cached**

Comment: framework7+framework7-react

Comment: {
    path: '/PageContainer/:id',
    component: PageContainer,
    title: 'detail',
  },